# Why and how we study different limits in quantum gravity?

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, approximations, ads-cft, branes

While I'm reading [an article](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9903165v2), I get confused by why and how we study different limits in quantum limit.

In this paper, the author introduced four limits in D0-brane quantum mechanics: the DKPS (Douglas–Kabat–Pouliot–Shenker) limit, the SSS (Susskind–Seiberg–Sen) limit, the BGLHKS (Balasubramanian–Gopakumar–Larsen–Hyun–Kiem–Shin) limit, and the IMSY (Itzhaki–Maldacena–Sonnenschein–Yankielowicz) limit.

For example, the DKPS limit is to take $g_s \rightarrow 0$ while holding fixed all of
$$N,P,q,M=g_s^{-1/3}l_s^{-1},\mathcal{H}=\frac{1}{g_sl_sM}(H-\frac{N}{g_sl_s}).$$

Another example is the 't Hooft limit which $N \rightarrow \infty $ and $\lambda=g^2N \rightarrow \infty$.

My question is:

1. Why is it important to take different limits of a theory?
2. How do they choose different parameters to be fixed or go to infinity? I have heard about the scaling analysis techniques, but I don't know how it works.
3. Do all the limit have interperation in physics? I think the $\lambda$ in 't Hooft limit seem to have no meaning in physics.

I would be grateful if anyone could give a simpler example to illsutrate the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but usually these limits are taken to make mathematical calculations possible. For instance when non-perturbative calculations are hard (basically every time) one can expand quantities with respect to a parameter and then look at the limit of the parameter going to zero. Given the equations in front of you is a matter of convenience to choose what to send to zero and what to keep fixed. The only constraint is that the limit must be consistent between all parameters.
As you mention, the downside is that many limits may not have a clear physical significance. But perhaps with these limits you can spot a duality or a relation between different areas and then conjecture that the duality works even non perturbatively.